# Как сделать так, чтобы в табличной верстке email текст обтекал блок?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы текст обтекал блок spec, как на картинке с версткой?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8e0bceeac7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,300,400,500,700,800,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<title>test</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

</head>

<body>

    <table style="margin: auto; max-width: 1200px; padding: 60px; box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; line-height: 1.6; font-size:16px;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style='font-size: 24px; text-align: center; padding: 60px 0 60px 0; font-weight: 500; '>PrimaLuna premium Pre silver</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color: #a0a0a0; text-align: justify; padding-bottom: 30px;"> <p>Ламповый  престижный        предварительный усилитель <a style="text-decoration: none; color: #23afff; border-bottom: 1px dotted #a9e0ff;" href="https://www.pult.ru/product/primaluna-dialogue-premium-pre-silver?ref=cpc_google&gclid=CjwKCAiAqJn9BRB0EiwAJ1SztetIA8JuL58IcFYpMGMQ5Fdr2XGkblzy8oonYZuDA5_vxC9x0rnc0BoC3Q8QAvD_BwE#about" target="_blank">PrimaLuna DiaLogue Premium Pre</a> относится к классу High End. Корпус его, отполированный вручную, изготовлен из металла и снаружи покрыт несколькими слоями глянцевого лака.</p>
                    <p>Два силовых трансформатора, находящихся на верхней части усилителя, закрыты кожухом с прорезами для вентиляции. Слева алюминиевого корпуса расположен регулятор громкости, а справа – селектор входов. После нажатия на кнопку питания, расположенную в левой части, загорается светодиод, который установлен посередине. Пульт дистанционного управления изготовлен из особого вида алюминия.</p>
                    <p>Главной особенностью данного предусилителя считается наличие шести двойных триодов 12AU7, т.е. не по два на канал, как у большинства моделей PrimaLuna, а по три. Такое отличие обеспечивает высокую пропускную способность и улучшение разрешения сигнала. Таким образом, выходной импеданс снизился до 256 Ом, а степень искажений снизилась в первом каскаде при малой громкости в 5 раз.</p>
            </td>
                
            <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 300px; padding-left: 60px;"><img src="photo.jpg" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 30px;" >

                <table style="font-size: 12px; width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #d0d0d0;">Потребляемая мощность, Вт</td>
                        <td style="padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #d0d0d0;">61</td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #d0d0d0;">Высота, мм</td>
                        <td style="padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #d0d0d0;">211</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #d0d0d0;">Ширина, мм</td>
                        <td style="padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #d0d0d0;">381</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td style="padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #d0d0d0;">Глубина, мм</td>
                       <td style="padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #d0d0d0;">361</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td style="padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #d0d0d0;">Вес, кг</td>
                       <td style="padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #d0d0d0;">24</td>
                    </tr>  
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
                    
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><a class="btn" 
               style="text-decoration: none; background-color: #a9e0ff; color: #fff; padding: 10px 40px; transition: 0.3s;"
               href="https://www.pult.ru/product/primaluna-dialogue-premium-pre-silver?ref=cpc_google&gclid=CjwKCAiAqJn9BRB0EiwAJ1SztetIA8JuL58IcFYpMGMQ5Fdr2XGkblzy8oonYZuDA5_vxC9x0rnc0BoC3Q8QAvD_BwE#about" target="_blank">Подробнее</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
                    
    </table>
    
                    
    
       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Использовать float. Именно для этого он и предназначен

Comment: float в таблице не работает вроде?

Comment: А зачем тут вообще таблица? И внутри ячеек таблицы флоат вполне себе работает

Comment: это же верстка email письма и как можно еще расположить фото с характеристиками друг под другом? Я вот не знаю

Comment: Я про таблицу для разметки